# Excel, pair 2 columns, then find all rows where column J is in two different Column D

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

SO I would like to have a formula or macro, to look at a table in Excel, pair two columns say J and M. Then find rows where M is connected to more then one value of Column J, Column J is Super Group, Column M is group. So i need to find where a group is in more then one super group.

Comment: Give us an example.

Comment: Column M has numbers, Column J has numbers column M has numbers column C is Item number. Look for rows where value of M is in row where column J is not = Column J of prior row column M is in.

Answer (score 0):

Past the following into any column in row 2 then copy to the entire range.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(M:M,M2,J:J,"<>J2")>0,"This group is also in another super group","").
```

It looks if the group listed on this row is listed in another row (any row in column M = M2) with a different super group (where column J is not = to J2).

Comment: Was this a satisfied answer? If yes, please mark as accepted. Otherwise, please edit your question to describe what’s not working.